# AngularJS : having multiple functions in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple controller in AngularJS, and i would like it to have 2 different functions :

```
var app = angular.module('searchApp', []);
app.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, $http, $log) {
    //1st function
    $scope.search = function() {
        $http.post('server.php', { "data" : $scope.keywords})
        .success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.result = data;
        })
    };

    //2nd function
    $scope.tableClick = function() {
          $log.log('Hello World!');
    };

})
```

I think there's an issue somewhere in the syntax because this script works only when i remove the 2nd function.

When i use the script with the 2 functions (so, what i posted), i get {{ x }} for the following html elements :

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in result">
<td><a href="wwww.test.com" >{{ x }}</a></td>
```

Any clues ?

Comment: There's no `echo 'Hello World!'` in javascript. Explain what you want to achieve with this, because the code is wrong in many ways.

Comment: I want to make an application with 2 buttons, each calling a different function. Sorry for the `echo`, i'm a bit tired. I have the same issue with console.log though

Comment: there is absolutely no reason that you couldn't have two different `$scope` properties that are both functions like this.  If you have replaced the `echo` statement and are still experiencing issues, you should consider updating the code in the question, rather than mentioning some other unknown combination in a comment, since that seems to be the main issue many are drawn to at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, there's no `echo 'Hello World!'` in javascript. If you want to write that phrase on the DOM, then you have to use it as a simple expression. Just like:

`$scope.helloWorld = 'Hello World!';`

and then in the HTML you simply call it like `{{helloWorld}}`.
I'm seeing you're testing it with a function. In this case you should `return` the string 'Hello World!' like

```
$scope.helloWorld = function () {
    return 'Hello World';
};
```

In the HTML:

```
{{ helloWorld() }}
```

In the case you want to simply "log" the `Hello World!` to the browser's console (which I doubt because you're not paying attention to JS errors): **DO NOT USE** `console.log();`. Use AngularJS' built-in service [$log](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log) instead

### A better code

Anyway, if I were you, I'd write that code differently. See

```
var app = angular.module('searchApp', []);
app.controller('searchCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $log) {
    //1st function
    $scope.search = function () {
        $http.post('server.php', { "data" : $scope.keywords })
        .then(function (resp) { //use then instead of success/error
            return resp.data;
        }, function inCaseOfErrors (err) { //named just for teaching purposes
            $log.log(err);
        });
    };

    //2nd function
    $scope.tableClick = function () {
        $log.log('Hello World!');
    };

})
```

Comment: Your second solution works just fine, thanks a lot. I understood the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your `$scope.result` has the right values. Also note that  `echo` doesn't exist in javascript.

In the code below, I took away the server-call and used hard-coded data, just to test:

```
var app = angular.module('searchApp', []);
app.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.result = ["apple", "orange", "raisin", "banana"];
    //1st function
    $scope.search = function() {

        //$http.post('server.php', { "data" : $scope.keywords})
        //.success(function(data, status) {
            //$scope.result = data;
        //})
    };

    //2nd function
    $scope.tableClick = function(item) {
        console.log("someone clicked the table! Row: " + item);
    };

})
```

Html:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in result">
       <td data-ng-click="tableClick(item)">{{ item }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```